# how to compile programs with .a and .h extension

Tags: c

Using osx how do I run a program I got on the internet that comes with a .a and another file that comes with a .h file.

I'm using a mac terminal.

Comment: .h files are headers. they are not compilable code. .a is compiled code already, ready to be linked into an executable.

Comment: That looks like a library. You don't usually run libraries.

Answer (score 3):

File with `.a` extension is an `archive library` and File with `.h` extension is a `header file` to expose the internals of the library.

These files cannot be run!

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the header (.h) in your source and link the library (here ``libx) using e.g.

```
gcc -o myprog myprog.c -L/path/to/libx -lx
```